# Mongo suddenly ignores index in large collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection with about 22 million documents, each quite small. This collection grows by thousands of records per day, so [according to this documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/query-plans/#read-operations-query-optimization) our query plans are invalidated all the time and rebuilt without issue.
A week ago I added a new index to this collection (in the background) and performed a few queries on it. About a day later, we experienced downtime and traced it back to routine queries (which are run against this collection probably every second) that were suddenly doing a full scan. I captured some profiling data which shows this.
To fix the issue, I restarted mongo, and it behaved for about another day before it occurred again. On a hunch, I removed the new index I had created, and we haven't seen the issue since.
Under what circumstances does mongo suddenly start ignoring an index? It might be the case that providing an index hint would work around this issue, but that would make me feel like all mongo queries I write, for any collection, should provide an index hint. Is that really necessary?

Edit: I can provide the offending query:
`Following.find( {user: userDoc._id, followedUser: {$exists: true}} )`

and the captured profile data:

```
{
    "op" : "query",
    "ns" : "figure1.following",
    "query" : {
        "$query" : {
            "followedUser" : {
                "$exists" : true
            },
            "user" : ObjectId("54243fce5fce0dcc0d2e23b3")
        },
        "orderby" : {
            "created" : -1
        }
    },
    "ntoreturn" : 0,
    "ntoskip" : 0,
    "nscanned" : 22542697,
    "nscannedObjects" : 22542697,
    "keyUpdates" : 0,
    "numYield" : 8645,
    "lockStats" : {
        "timeLockedMicros" : {
            "r" : NumberLong(720504269),
            "w" : NumberLong(0)
        },
        "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
            "r" : NumberLong(26364170),
            "w" : NumberLong(2108)
        }
    },
    "nreturned" : 2,
    "responseLength" : 82,
    "millis" : 390517,
    "execStats" : {
        "type" : "PROJECTION",
        "works" : 22542699,
        "yields" : 178440,
        "unyields" : 178440,
        "invalidates" : 0,
        "advanced" : 2,
        "needTime" : 0,
        "needFetch" : 0,
        "isEOF" : 1,
        "children" : [
            {
                "type" : "FETCH",
                "works" : 22542699,
                "yields" : 178440,
                "unyields" : 178440,
                "invalidates" : 0,
                "advanced" : 2,
                "needTime" : 22542696,
                "needFetch" : 0,
                "isEOF" : 1,
                "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                "forcedFetches" : 0,
                "matchTested" : 2,
                "children" : [
                    {
                        "type" : "IXSCAN",
                        "works" : 22542698,
                        "yields" : 178440,
                        "unyields" : 178440,
                        "invalidates" : 0,
                        "advanced" : 22542697,
                        "needTime" : 1,
                        "needFetch" : 0,
                        "isEOF" : 1,
                        "keyPattern" : "{ created: 1.0 }",
                        "isMultiKey" : 0,
                        "boundsVerbose" : "field #0['created']: [MaxKey, MinKey]",
                        "yieldMovedCursor" : 0,
                        "dupsTested" : 0,
                        "dupsDropped" : 0,
                        "seenInvalidated" : 0,
                        "matchTested" : 0,
                        "keysExamined" : 22542697,
                        "children" : [ ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "ts" : ISODate("2015-02-06T21:09:43.550Z"),
    "client" : "10.165.78.55",
    "allUsers" : [ ],
    "user" : ""
}
```

Both `followedUser` and `user` are indexed individually, together, and with the `created` field. The problem started about a day after I added an index on the `created` field (which you can see in the profile data as the sort field). I realize that $exists won't use an index, and that's something I can change, but my concern is that mongo seems to have chosen a really bad query plan.

Additional note: the problem first happened in mongo 2.6.4, which I can see had an issue that looks very similar to this ([JIRA-14961](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-14961)). But after I killed mongo and restarted it, it was running 2.6.6, and the issue occurred again, so I don't think it's exactly the issue in bug 14961.

Comment: Without having access to your data and indexes, the best advice I could give would to be call `explain()` on your query and post the results here.

Comment: The query planner opted for a different index and cached that query plan for your query shape. But, without seeing the queries and the `explain(true)` output for them, there's not much more that can be said about why.

Comment: added some info, hopefully that helps.

Comment: Could this have been your issue?https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-15802

Comment: @AndrewLavers that really sounds like it! Happy to mark this as an answer if you add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run into this exact issue myself and I suspect this might have been the cause:

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-15802

After upgrading from 2.6.3 to 2.6.9 I haven't seen it recur (so far).